# Is it allowed to perform Hajj/Umrah, if you got debt to pay?

Tags: hajj, umrah, debt

Someone has a debt to pay but instead of paying it, he/she decided to go for Hajj/Umrah.

Is it allowed to perform Hajj or Umrah while having debt?

Or is it that only after clearing the debt he/she is allowed to perform Hajj/Umrah.

Comment: Walaikum Salam.
The question is about to perform Hajj/Umrah while having debt to pay. I've edited it for the better understanding. Let me know if further editing required.

Answer (score 0):

[Narrated Abu Huraira (Bukhari):](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/38/1)

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Procrastination (delay) in paying debts by a
>   wealthy man is injustice. So, if your debt is transferred from your
>   debtor to a rich debtor, you should agree."

[Narrated Abu Huraira (Tirmidhi):](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/10/114)

> The Messenger of Allah said: "The believer's soul is suspended by his
>   debt until it is settled for him."

[Narrated Abu Huraira (Sahih al-Bukhari):](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/69/21)

> A dead man in debt used to be brought to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) who
>   would ask, "Has he left anything to re pay his debts?" If he was
>   informed that he had left something to cover his debts the Prophet (ﷺ)
>   would offer the funeral prayer for him; otherwise he would say to the
>   Muslims present there), "Offer the funeral prayer for your friend:"but
>   when Allah helped the Prophet (ﷺ) to gain victory (on his
>   expeditions), he said, "I am closer to the Believers than themselves,
>   so. if one of the Believers dies in debt, I will repay it, but if he
>   leaves wealth, it will be for his heirs.

I could not found a single Hadith or Ayah from Quran which says, that we cannot perform Hajj/Umra while having debt.

But from the above Hadith, it is very clear, we need to pay the debt first because **Hajj/Umra is not obligatory until you have debt free money**.

Some scholar says, if you can take time from the person, but what if you could not return from Hajj/Umra?

[For more Hadith on debt, see these, hope it will help to understand!](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=debt)

Answer (score -1):

Consider this answer from Sh Karim Abu Zaid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrLkXioCLXE