# Can we perform hajj or umrah with loan money?

Tags: fiqh, hajj, umrah, loan

I am not having money to perform my ummrah I have taken some money from my elder sister as a loan and I know that i could return her later.
So is this allowed in Islam or should we have our own money?

Comment: See also [Is it allowed to perform hajj or umrah if you got debt to pay?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49235/is-it-allowed-to-perform-hajj-umrah-if-you-got-debt-to-pay?rq=1) which seems a duplicate of this post. Also note do you also know that you would return alive from Hajj or Umrah?

Answer (score 1):

> The islamic scholars are in agreement that Hajj is only obligatory on those who are capable of that because Allah said: {And [due] to Allah from the people is a pilgrimage to the House - for whoever is able to find thereto a way} [Quran 4:97] and part of the capability is to have enough money to cover the expenses of the journey as well as the expenses of those whom the person is responsible for until returning back. As for borrowing money to perform Hajj, the scholars agreed that it is not obligatory to do so. Al-Nawawi said, “It is not obligatory for a person to borrow money so that they can perform Hajj. This is a ruling that no one disagreed with.” Al-Majmoo’ Sharh al-Muhadhab (7/61) However, they differed in opinion regarding the ruling on borrowing money for this purpose, after they agreed that it is not obligatory. The Shafi’e scholars said if one can repay the debt and the creditor agrees [that the debtor travels for the pilgrimage], then it is permissible. This is also the view of Sufyan al-Thawri. Ibn ‘Abdullah said in al-Tamheed (9/135), “If a man is poor and he did not perform Hajj, I dislike that he takes a loan and asks people for money so that he can perform Hajj.” As for the Hanafi scholars, they said the man should borrow money to perform Hajj if he was capable of its performance earlier in life but neglected it until he become incapable, even if he cannot repay the debt.  This was mentioned by Ibn ‘Abdeen in his Hashyah (2/457). As for Maliki scholars, they have two views regarding this issue – taking the loan is either forbidden or disliked if the man cannot repay the debt, as stated by Al-Khattab in Mawahib al-Jaleel (2/507). It appears to me that one should not burden himself with that which Allah did not obligate him to do. Imam al-Shafi’e reported a Hadith that ‘Abdullah Abi Awfa (may Allah be pleased with him) asked the Prophet (may the Salah and Salam of Allah be upon him): “Should a man who has not performed Hajj borrow money to do it?” He replied: “No”. ([Source](https://www.almosleh.com/ar/index-en-show-18043.html))

If I conclude than majority of Muslim Scholar agrees not to perform Hajj or Umra by getting loan for travel & stay expenditures at Holy places MAKKAH& MADINA.

Comment: This is mainly a copy paste and you should mark your quotes from other sources and make a clear distinction between your own words and quotes and share a link to the source of your quotes.